# Why Java EE is widely used in complicated projects?

Tags: java-ee-5

Yesterday me and my friend we've had nice conversation about IT and he asked me WHY Java EE is so widely used when it comes to build complicated IT systems? From my point of view advantages are easily visible, but he is IT manager with a lot of Microsoft experience (and little Java exp.), so I would like to hear your voice. And I'll give him a link of course.

I don't want new .NET - Java war - just - why Java EE :)

Answer (score 6):

Java's advantage is that it is a popular platform (i.e. lots of developers know it) that's relatively easy to use, runs on multiple operating systems, and is fairly capable.  So you can get stuff done with it.  It's not always the best tool for the job but most of the time it's an adequate tool that's low-risk, and lots of the time it is among the best choices you can make for your task.  Business isn't about the best computer technology, it's about return on investment, and Java lets you get a decent return on your developer investment.

Answer (score 3):

Most complex systems are distributed. Distributed computing is difficult. Jave EE is an attempt to mask the complexities (scalability with services like JMS, distributed transactions, distributed scope management, etc.) and allow the programming to remain focused on the business problem not the technical one.